# Hydroponics Tomato plants dying

Tags: leaves, tomatoes, fungus, hydroponic

It’s my first time growing anything and I decided to try growing Tiny Tim tomatoes in an Idoo 10 pod hydroponics system. I have been adding the nutrients that came with the system and have been deep cleaning the system every two weeks and adding water in between to maintain 4.5l. I’ve been adding 13ml of 3% hydrogen peroxide to the water too every 5 days. Originally there were 10 plants in this system but I removed two weaker ones as they were dying and very small.

I noticed a few weeks ago the lower leaves have started to die and fall off and this has been slowly spreading upwards. The leaves appear to have some brownish circular looking things on it and I’m not sure if this is a fungus that is spreading or what I should do? I’m a complete newbie to growing anything so any help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYPdK.jpg

Comment: Maybe it's verticillium wilt.  https://www.smartgardener.com/plants/3574-tomato-tiny-tim/diseases/784-verticillium-wilt

Comment: "I’ve been adding 13ml of hydrogen peroxide to the water" to me this sounds like a horrible problem but let us allow someone more knowledgeable comment or hopefully answer.

Comment: @Vorac See my edit, Only 3% hydrogen peroxide which seems to be quite a common thing in hydroponics I’ve been told

Comment: Yeah, I over-reacted and also didn't know it's a thing. Best of luck!